# What does "Stan" in "PHPStan" refer to/mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, names

I found this the other day and have started using it: https://phpstan.org/ It's nice. But it really annoys me that nowhere does it explain/mention what "Stan" refers to.

- It's not the name of the author.
- It's not obviously (to me) related to analyzing programming code.
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stan#English does not give me any clues.
- I've searched online and looked through its entire website without finding any mention of the name.

You'd think that this page would mention it, but it really doesn't mention it anywhere on its entire website: https://phpstan.org/blog/find-bugs-in-your-code-without-writing-tests

Any ideas? I'm really annoyed by this and would love to know what it means.

Comment: Only the site owner will know for sure. Perhaps they live in one of the -stans...Afghanistan, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, Pakistan, Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, or Uzbekistan...and named it based on that?

Comment: @KillingTime: Or perhaps they want to represent that site as a "country" by affixing the *-stan* suffix to the end of PHP (a popular web programming language).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [first blog post](https://phpstan.org/blog/find-bugs-in-your-code-without-writing-tests), introducing the tool, describes it as a "static analysis tool." I must assume that "STAN" is a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) of "static" and "analysis." A little searching shows it used in other contexts that concern "structure analysis" as well.

Comment: I think both you and [@Jim Mack](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/579376/205983) are correct and this was intentional word play :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is connected, but ***Stan*** (from the Eminem song of that name) is common slang for "an overzealous, maniacal fan for any celebrity or athlete". Or, presumably, for a programming language. Per the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stan). I've even heard it used as a verb -- "stanning" over something.

Answer (score -1):

It should be noted that "Stan" is a slightly dated pun on Afghanistan, Pakistan, etc.  The implication is that the "territory" being denoted is a primitive, backward place.  Back in the 60s-70s it was common to use the -stan terminal (something like "Bullwinkle-stan") to identify (especially in cartoons) a fictitious country with no particular merit.